# Pass back a value from an Activity when the calling activity finishes

Tags: java, android

I have Activity A, B, and C.  Both Activity A and B have an option in the OptionsMenu to call activity C.  However, if the user calls activity C from activity B I want them to return to activity A when activity C finishes.  I can just use finish() after I call the activity from activity B, but how would I pass back a value to activity A if the intent was called from activity B?

To recap, I want to:

User is in activity B -> Calls activity C -> User returns to activity A, which receives a value from activity C.

Comment: you can use a localbroadcastreceiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Activity A from Activity C and finish Activity C. To send data to Activity A use intent.putExtra();

```
Intent i=new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityA.class);
i.putExtra("Key","value you want to pass to activity A");
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: @user3264455 and what will happen if you press back button form activity A?

Comment: @Raghunandan It would exit the app, I suppose.  I am making a pretty simple app for an assignment so that will be fine in this case. That is something I intend to handle on the apps that I make outside of school.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `startActivityForResult()` to start activity C

```
static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and then override `onActivityResult()` method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("B", "Entered onActivityResult()");

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){
        myTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("MY_VALUE"));
    } 
}
```

to get back the data. ([Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29))

In activity C you need to set data like -

```
Intent intent  = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("MY_VALUE",input );
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Comment: So you are saying override the onActivityResult() method in activity B?  What would I do to get it to pass something back to A?

Comment: Same goes for A as well. When you start Activity C from A then call startActivityForResult() from A and overrride onActivityResult() in A to collect the result passed by Activity C.